# Everything on screen got smaller when updated to windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, resolution, windows-8.1-upgrade

When I updated from Windows 8 to 8.1 everything got smaller on the screen. The text, menus, programs etc. The modern UI is still the same size but the desktop is smaller. I haven't changed any settings and my resolution is 1920*1080.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. so I figured it out:
Go to desktop > Right click > screen resolution > Make text and other items larger or smaller > Check the box you find there > choose 125% and save and log out > log in. Now it looks normal

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your DPI. It also affects the size apart from resolution.

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6894-make-everything-your-screen-bigger-turn-off.html

Comment: When I try that. only The Modern UI changes. And when I make it bigger the "windows 7" way to do it it looks fine first. the desktop, icons and stuff looks like they used to before the update. But when I open a program it looks way to big and also blurry.